# DB2 Query multiple select and sum by date

Tags: db2

I have 3 tables: ITEMS, ODETAILS, OHIST.

- ITEMS - a list of products, ID is the key field
- ODETAILS - line items of every order, no key field
- OHIST - a view showing last years order totals by month

```
ITEMS             ODETAILS                                 OHIST
+----+----------+  +-----+---------+---------+----------+  +---------+-------+
| ID |   NAME   |  | OID |  ODUE   | ITEM_ID | ITEM_QTY |  | ITEM_ID | M5QTY |
+----+----------+  +-----+---------+---------+----------+  +---------+-------+
| 10 + Widget10 |  | A33 | 1180503 |    10   |    100   |  |    10   |  1000 |
+----+----------+  +-----+---------+---------+----------+  +---------+-------+
| 11 + Widget11 |  | A33 | 1180504 |    11   |    215   |  |    11   |  1500 |
+----+----------+  +-----+---------+---------+----------+  +---------+-------+
| 12 + Widget12 |  | A34 | 1180505 |    10   |    500   |  |    12   |  2251 |
+----+----------+  +-----+---------+---------+----------+  +---------+-------+
| 13 + Widget13 |  | A34 | 1180504 |    11   |    320   |  |    13   |  4334 |
+----+----------+  +-----+---------+---------+----------+  +---------+-------+
                   | A34 | 1180504 |    12   |    450   |
                   +-----+---------+---------+----------+
                   | A34 | 1180505 |    13   |    125   |
                   +-----+---------+---------+----------+
```

Assuming today is May 2, 2018 (1180502).
I want my results to show ID, NAME, M5QTY, and SUM(ITEM_QTY) grouped by day 
over the next 3 days (D1, D2, D3)

```
Desired Result
+----+----------+--------+------+------+------+
| ID |   NAME   | M5QTY  |  D1  |  D2  |  D3  |
+----+----------+--------+------+------+------+
| 10 | Widget10 |  1000  |  100 |      |  500 |
+----+----------+--------+------+------+------+
| 11 | Widget11 |  1500  |      |  535 |      |
+----+----------+--------+------+------+------+
| 12 | Widget12 |  2251  |      |  450 |      |
+----+----------+--------+------+------+------+
| 13 | Widget13 |  4334  |      |      |  125 |
+----+----------+--------+------+------+------+
```

This is how I convert ODUE to a date

```
DATE(concat(concat(concat(substr(char((ODETAILS.ODUE-1000000)+20000000),1,4),'-'), concat(substr(char((ODETAILS.ODUE-1000000)+20000000),5,2), '-')), substr(char((ODETAILS.ODUE-1000000)+20000000),7,2)))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (you can add the joins you need)

```
SELECT  ITEM_ID
,     SUM(CASE WHEN ODUE = INT(CURRENT DATE) - 19000000 + 1 THEN ITEM_QTY ELSE 0 END) AS D1
,     SUM(CASE WHEN ODUE = INT(CURRENT DATE) - 19000000 + 2 THEN ITEM_QTY ELSE 0 END) AS D2
,     SUM(CASE WHEN ODUE = INT(CURRENT DATE) - 19000000 + 3 THEN ITEM_QTY ELSE 0 END) AS D3
FROM
    ODETAILS
GROUP BY
    ITEM_ID
```